# Left align text in the listings package

Tags: listings

I want the text to be "left aligned" in MS Word jargon, in the listings.

Please see the snip below. Notice the amount of white space before and after the word "first" are different. I do not want the extra white space after "first".

[image]

Below is the code that produces this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    deletekeywords={from,in,and},
    morekeywords={function,Algorithm,algorithm, then,do},
    mathescape=true,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,
    breaklines=true,
    flexiblecolumns=true
}
\begin{lstlisting}
            Z = Y(from 1 to rand(1, Size(P(j))) # from the first till a random value

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{figure caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need columns=fullflexible

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    deletekeywords={from,in,and},
    morekeywords={function,Algorithm,algorithm, then,do},
    mathescape=true,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    flexiblecolumns=true,
}
\begin{lstlisting}
            Z = Y(from 1 to rand(1, Size(P(j))) # from the first till a random value

\end{lstlisting}
\caption{figure caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```